# When getting a hexadecimal dump in VS, what do those periods mean?

Tags: binary

For example:

```
%PDF-1.3..%.....
...1 0 obj..<<..
```

from

```
25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 33 0D 0A 25 E2 E3 CF D3 0D
0A 0D 0A 31 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 0D 0A
```

Do they represent numbers that don't fit in ASCII?

Comment: Probably "non-printable characters". And no, I don't know the exact criteria for that distinction.